# List down multiple files in datatable to download

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets

[image: Files I need to List on my page]

I've MySQL table which contains list of files I need to populate in a table on my jsp page. I've attached the screen shot of table contents.  I was referring example given [here](http://java.candidjava.com/tutorial/File-download-example-using-servlet-and-jsp.htm). But example given is just for one file. It would be really helpful if experts can point me to an example to follow... 
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: in which format you want data

Comment: first give all the links in your jsp by fetching from mysql with filenames. Then on click of link pass file name to your servlet which download that file

Comment: Hi Mohit, I just need to list them in table on my jsp, there should be "download" link against each record. If user clicks that - particular file will be downloaded

Comment: @NVJ below answer shows how you can populate result from DB,

Once you achieve  this , then you can easily send Ajax request to you controller/Servlet with document ID and can fetch individual document

Proper Structure of Program is required If you are not using any framework like Spring/hibernate try using below:
DAO(data access Object)

Answer (score 0):

First Step:
Database to Controller:
Grab Data from your database by creating DAO(data access Object)
For Example:

```
    public class Document {
        String document_name;
        String document_date;
        String document_RevisedName;
        public String getDocument_name() {
            return document_name;
        }
        public void setDocument_name(String document_name) {
            this.document_name = document_name;
        }
        public String getDocument_date() {
            return document_date;
        }
        public void setDocument_date(String document_date) {
            this.document_date = document_date;
        }
        public String getDocument_RevisedName() {
            return document_RevisedName;
        }
        public void setDocument_RevisedName(String document_RevisedName) {
            this.document_RevisedName = document_RevisedName;
        }


    }
```

Create a Interface Document_DAO:

```
    public interface Document_DAO {
        ArrayList<Document>getAllDocuments();

    }
```

Implement above Interface to a Implementation Class **Document_DAO_Imp**

```
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;

    import Utils.DataSource;
    import dao_class.Class;

    public class Docuemnt_DAO_IMp implements Document_DAO{
        Connection conn = null;
        DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
        PreparedStatement  preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        String query= "";
        ArrayList<Document> documentList= new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public ArrayList<Document> getAllDocuments() {
            conn = (Connection) dataSource.createConnection();
            try{
                query = "SELECT * FROM youTableName";
                preparedStatement = conn.clientPrepareStatement(query);
                resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

                while (resultSet.next()) {
                    Document  doc= new Document();
                    doc.setDocument_date(resultSet.getString("youRowName"));
                    doc.setDocument_RevisedName(resultSet.getString("youRowName"));
                    documentList.add(doc);
                }
            }
            catch(SQLException sqlE){
                System.out.println(sqlE.toString());
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    resultSet.close();
                    preparedStatement.close();
                    conn.close();

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                } 
            }
            return documentList;
        }

    }
```

Finally:
Call above DAO from your Controller/Servlet.

```
ArrayList<Document> docList = new ArrayList<>();
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                Document_DAO dao = new Document_DAO_Imp();
                docList = dao.getAllDocuments();
                JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
                JsonElement jsonElement = null;
                if (classList.size()!=0) {
                    jsonElement = new Gson().toJsonTree(docList);
                    jsonObject.add("docList", jsonElement);
                    jsonObject.addProperty("success", "true");
                }
                else{
                    jsonObject.addProperty("success", "true");
                }
                response.getWriter().println(jsonObject);

            }


        }
```

Till Now You have successfully,Grabed data from DB and Send to you JSP/HTML Page.
Make Sure to add GSON a google library to add to you built path and WEB-INF/lib folder.

Now Using jquery we can parse result to page and can also download them in XLS format.

To Fetch Data using Jquery Ajax you can either provide a event or you can load data on page load.
$(document).load(function(){
});

```
            $.ajax({
                type:"get",
                url : "DocumentServlet",
                dataType: 'json',
                // if received a response from the server
                success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log("Getting Document Information!");
                if (data.success == 'true') {
                data = data.docList;
                console.log(data);
                $('.table').html("");
                $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                      var eachrow = "<tr><td>"+value.documentName
                      +"</td><td>"+value.documentRevisedName
                      +"</td></tr>";
                      $('.table').append(eachrow);
                 });

                }else{
                    console.log("failure");

                    }
                },
                error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                }
            });
```

One you successfully populate JSON array to tables.

Then you can use any external Library to convert data to XLS and download.
First use this Structure to create a page,,Then i'll provide code to download

Comment: Hi Mohit, I'll try this and let you know if I've any questions. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @NVJ  At any point you can let me know, if you have anything you don't understand in my solution.